# How is Mongo ObjectId Compared Internally?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**TLDR: There is no difference between `ObjectId("LowerCaseHexString")` and `ObjectId("UpperCaseHexString")` when running Mongo Shell commands.**

Just a careless mistake on my part...

Original Qn:

I've just noticed some ***very*** quirky behavior while executing a couple of commands, to remove some array elements in a sub-document, in the Mongo Shell.

This has to do with whether an **uppercase** or **lowercase** hexadecimal string is used while constructing object ids i.e. `ObjectId("UpperOrLowerCaseString")`

Firstly, both these queries return the document:

```
db.users.findOne({"id":1, "SubDoc._id":{$lt: ObjectId("54B4EF540000000000000000")}})
db.users.findOne({"id":1, "SubDoc._id":{$lt: ObjectId("54b4ef540000000000000000")}})
```

And both of these do not (note that the `$lt` has been replaced with `$gt`):

```
db.users.findOne({"id":1, "SubDoc._id":{$gt: ObjectId("54B4EF540000000000000000")}})
db.users.findOne({"id":1, "SubDoc._id":{$gt: ObjectId("54b4ef540000000000000000")}})
```

Which is expected. ***HOWEVER*** when trying to `$pull` elements from the sub-document, the following query works:

```
db.users.update(
    {"id":1}, 
    {$pull:
        {"SubDoc":
            {_id: {$lt: ObjectId("54b4ef540000000000000000")}}
        }
    }
)
```

While this does not (note the change from lowercase to uppercase):

```
db.users.update(
    {"id":1}, 
    {$pull:
        {"SubDoc":
            {_id: {$lt: ObjectId("54B4EDC40000000000000000")}}
        }
    }
)
```

Interestingly enough this works (note the `$lt` replaced with `$gt`):

```
db.users.update(
    {"id":1}, 
    {$pull:
        {"SubDoc":
            {_id: {$gt: ObjectId("54B4EDC40000000000000000")}}
        }
    }
)
```

Which leads me to believe that in the case of `update`, the actual string values are being used to compare the object ids (the lowercase string being larger due to byte representation).

Where as in the case of `findOne`, this does not seem to be the case i.e. Object Ids are converted to their 12 byte form before being compared.

Hopefully this is not a mistake on my part (quite prone to those)...

But anyone care to shed some light? Especially on the inconsistency of behaviors between my `findOne` and `update` queries?

And if indeed the full string values are bring used for comparison, then isn't that pretty worrying performance wise? I.e. comparing 24 bytes each time instead of just 12?

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't think you understood my question. Although the answer now is painfully obvious (thanks to @JohnnyHK), I did have a genuine concern about the way MongoIds could have been compared. Also, if you're going to put people down with statements like "need to read and understand a lot more than your current level of knowledge" & "wrong way and place to ask", then do at least point them in the right direction. If there is a more suitable way / place to ask these questions, or some key piece of documentation I am missing out on, do let me know and I would be most thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference in the ObjectIDs that result from using lower-case or upper-case versions of the same hex value. You're seeing different results because you're using different hex values in the two cases:

```js
ObjectId("54b4ef540000000000000000")
...            ^^
ObjectId("54B4EDC40000000000000000")
```

Comment: Sigh.. indeed... indeed. Thanks for your sharp eyes. How embarrassing!